# Run Mercurial simultaneousily with Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I am currently using Mercurial as version control tool but Subversion is the approved version control tool by my company. Is it's possible to run the two simultaneously in a same repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Mercurial + [HGSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) extention. But for "...in a same repository..." - *to some degree*: you work with local own Mercurial repo, which have external SVN-repo as pull|push target

`hg help subversion` is a **must read** after activating hgsubversion